# What does "miss errors" mean in this sentence?

Tags: sentence-meaning

> How often do you miss errors in your work?

What does it mean by saying "miss errors"? It is a part of an assessment test.

Answer (score 3):

It means don't **notice** the errors.
According to Webster New world college dictionary one of the meanings of **miss** is:

> to fail to meet, reach, attain, catch, accomplish, see, hear,
>   perceive, understand, etc.

Answer (score 2):

It could suggest a failure to review your own work. Other ways to say the same thing:

- "How often do you submit work that has errors?"
- "How frequently do you fail to review your work and not notice that you have made an errors?"